# angularjs variable not showing when called before $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular app, i have a message service to display info, loading and error messages for my app. It looks like that:

```
module.factory('msgSvc', function(){
    var current_message = '';

    return {
        message: function(){
            return current_message;
       },
       setMessage: function(msg){
            console.log('setting message: '+ msg);
            current_message = msg;
        },
        clear: function(){ current_message = null; current_style = null}
    }
});
```

and in my view i have

```
<span class="pull-left label label-warning" >{{ msg.message() }}</span>
```

I have a login controller, when the user submits the form i want to show a "logging you in..." message while an ajax login is sent. and an error message if there was an error. here's my code:

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $http, msgSvc) {
   [...]
   $scope.login = function(creds) {
    console.log(creds);
    msgSvc.setMessage('Logging in...');

    $http.post('http://...',creds)
        .success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            [...]
            msgSvc.clear();
            $location.path('/');

        })
        .error(function(data, status){
           console.log(status);
            msgSvc.setMessage('Wrong username or password.');

        });

   };
}
```

`login()` is called by the submit form, `Logging in...` never shows even though the function is called (it appears in the console). but the error message appears.

am i doing something wrong?

**edit: the login form**

```
<form class="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="loginCreds.username" required />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="loginCreds.password" required />
   <button ng-click="login(loginCreds)">Login</button>
</form>
```

**edit 2**
If it changes anything, there are many controllers setting messages in the service and in the actual code, the controller showing the message (where the `$scope.msg` variable is set) is different from the one setting the message.

```
function BodyCtrl($scope, msgSvc) {
    $scope.msg = msgSvc;
}
```

Comment: How is the login-method called?

Comment: @AleksanderBlomskøld added the form to the question

Comment: What happens if you try just setting $scope.msg to msgSvc.message and then just calling msg()?

Comment: @chaft Is your intention to call `setMessage` and have the same message displayed in multiple places or each controller that uses `msgSvc` set it's own message?

Comment: @marcoseu each controller setts its own message. and only the latest message is displayed. or no message is displayed if clear is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple problems with your implementation:

1. As the message is being set in a private variable, you would need use `$watch` for the message to be displayed;
2. A `.factory` is a singleton and therefore `setMessage` would have set the same message for all controllers.

The simplest solution is to pass the controller's `$scope` to the `svcMsg`:

```
app.factory("msgSvc", function () {
  return function (scope) {
    var priv_scope = scope;

    this.setMessage = function (msg) {
      console.log('setting message: '+ msg);
      priv_scope.message = msg;
    };

    this.clear = function () {
      priv_scope.message = "";
    };

  };
});
```

In you controller, you would then do:

```
var msg = new msgSvc($scope);
```

In case you **do** want to propagate the message to all controllers, use `$rootScope`:

```
app.service("msgSvc", function ($rootScope) {
    var priv_scope = $rootScope;

    this.setMessage = function (msg) {
      console.log('setting message: '+ msg);
      priv_scope.message = msg;
    };

    this.clear = function () {
      priv_scope.message = "";
    };
});
```

Check out this Plunker using `$rootScope`:
http://plnkr.co/edit/NYEABNvjrk8diNTwc3pP?p=preview

As $rootScope is really a global variable in Angular, you shouldn't abuse it.  It can also be problematic if you accidentally set the `$scope.message` in controllers.  An alternative is to use `$watch` to detect the change to the `message`:

```
// In your controller, do:
$scope.$watch(
  function () {
    return msgSvc.message;
  },
  function () {
    $scope.message = msgSvc.message;
  }
)
```

Here is an example using `$watch`:
http://plnkr.co/edit/vDV2mf?p=info

Comment: concerning the 2nd point, I want the message to be the same for all controllers. It only displays the latest message. for the 1st point, if i have my message variable public and instead of setMessage, i just set it, same for the views, would it work better?

Comment: In that case, use `$rootScope` instead of passing the `$scope` from controller. Updated the answer and Plunker.

Comment: and would it work with the parent scope? if all the controllers setting the message have the same parent and i need to access the message from their common parent?

Comment: @chaft if you use `$rootScope`, yes, as long as you never set `$scope.message` in your controllers.  You might want to choose a more unique variable name for `message` if you decide to go with `$rootScope`.  Remember: `$rootScope` is parent to all `$scope`s.

Answer (score 0):

Set `$scope.msg` in each place you want to display the value on the view:

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $http, msgSvc) {
   [...]
   $scope.msg = "";
   $scope.login = function(creds) {
    console.log(creds);
    $scope.msg = msgSvc.setMessage('Logging in...');

    $http.post('http://...',creds)
        .success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            [...]
            $scope.msg = msgSvc.clear();
            $location.path('/');

        })
        .error(function(data, status){
           console.log(status);
            $scope.msg = msgSvc.setMessage('Wrong username or password.');

        });

   };
}
```

I know you may be trying to avoid that but the changes in its value are not being propagated.

Comment: the thing that there are many controllers writing to that service, and the actual `$scope.msg` is in another controller that's different from the one setting the message. i simplified a bit in my question

Answer (score -1):

Add $apply to in error()

```
  function LoginCtrl($scope, $http, msgSvc) {
             [...]

        $scope.login = function(creds) {
        console.log(creds);

        msgSvc.setMessage('Logging in...');
        $scope.msg = msgSvc;



       $http.post('http://...',creds)
              .success(function(data){
                 console.log(data);
                 [...]
                 msgSvc.clear();
                 $location.path('/');
               })
              .error(function(data, status){
                   $scope.$apply(function() {
                      msgSvc.setMessage('Wrong username or password.');
                   });
            });
      };
   }
```

SEE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FhKR8/1/)

Comment: But i don't have a problem with the error message. it's the `logging in` message that's not appearing

Comment: I get an `Error: $apply already in progress` if i added around the login message

Comment: $apply for the error is still raising and exception. I updated my question to clarify how the `$scope.msg` is set in a different controller